# Linux partitioning vs. mount file system declaration

Tags: filesystems, mount, partition, flash-memory

I'm looking a Linux device where `blkid` shows an eMMC partition type as `ext2`:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p32: UUID="1c48ca57-c9eb-4ed1-a51a-212f7d1fd40e" TYPE="ext2" PARTLABEL="configs" PARTUUID="2214f85a-ce4e-fea2-0613-8c93121f02e1"
```

but that partition, according to `cat /proc/mounts` is mounted as `ext4`:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p32 /configs ext4 rw,relatime,block_validity,barrier,user_xattr 0 0
```

What file system type is actually in use? Why is a partition in this case allowed to have a different type than its mount target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`blkid`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/blkid.8.html) determines the type of the device's content based on the content metadata. In your case, `/dev/mmcblk0p32` is actually formatted as an `ext2` file system.

On the other hand, the file system type in `/proc/mounts` has the same semantics of [`mount`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html)'s `-t` option: the type from the kernel's point of view (i.e. the driver to use).

The `ext4` file system driver can, and is apparently commonly used to, mount `ext2` and `ext3` file systems too. From [`man 5 ext4`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ext4.5.html):

> ... They are general purpose file systems that have been designed for extensibility and backwards compatibility.  In particular, file systems previously intended for use with the ext2 and ext3 file systems can be mounted using the ext4 file system driver, and indeed in many modern Linux distributions, the ext4 file system driver has been configured to handle mount requests for ext2 and ext3 file systems.

Your `/dev/mmcblk0p32` have likely been mounted passing `-t ext4` to `mount` on the command line or using `ext4` as the type in `fstab`.

Comment: ok so as I assumed it is still an ext2 in this case, it's just using a backwards compatible driver.